# Nested IFs to pad numbers with zeroes

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, formula

I am looking to pad a columns with zero's so that I can later concatenate it's value. It needs to 4 characters, so I am trying to use a Nested If Statement.

```
=IF(LEN(G2)=3,"0" & G2),IF(LEN(G2)=2,"00" & G2,G2)
```

I only get '#Value'. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel: there is already a built-in function do to this.

```
=TEXT(G2,"0000")
```

[image]

Now, to answer your question specifically, the reason you got your error was that your `IF` functions weren't properly nested due to misplaced right brackets `)`.

Was:

```
=IF(LEN(G2)=3,"0" & G2),IF(LEN(G2)=2,"00" & G2,G2)
                      ^
```

Should be:

```
=IF(LEN(G2)=3,"0" & G2,IF(LEN(G2)=2,"00" & G2,G2))
                                                 ^
```

Still, this won't give you the expected results. Just go with the built-in `TEXT` function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need nested `IF`'s. Just concatenate 4 "0"s with your text, and then rip off the right 4 digits.

```
=RIGHT(CONCATENATE(REPT("0",4), G2),4)
```