# Padding a word with spaces to fill a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to pad a cell with spaces to ensure that it is the correct length?

Here's an example with `*` representing spaces.

```
Input    Output
-----    ------
red      red**
blue     blue*
```

The words are padded with spaces to ensure the cell content is 5 characters long.

Comment: What should happen when the input is e.g. `turquoise` i.e. longer than the 5-character limit? Truncate to `turqu`? Leave as is? Something else? And: WHY on Earth do you want to pad a cell with spaces in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Related, but for numbers padded with zeroes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943527/nested-ifs-to-pad-numbers-with-zeroes

Comment: Did you mean update the same cell as the entry was made?

Comment: If it is too long it would be good to truncate.

Comment: The input field would be separate to the output field and would truncate if too long.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

`=LEFT(A1&"*****",5)`

We are adding lots of stars(*) then just cutting from `left` 5 characters.

[image]

Comment: This method can be reversed to provide leading zeroes to special numbers destined to be exported to a database. Some part numbers, serial numbers and in particular DUNS numbers must be padded with leading zeroes to a fixed length. `=RIGHT("000000000" & A1, 9)` will produce the correct result.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, this is how I would pad numbers to have the same length. Another option would be `=TEXT(A1,"0000")` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3992588/680068

Answer (score 23):

As per suggested comment:

`=LEFT(A1 & REPT("*",5),5)`

original:

`=A1 & REPT("*",5-len(A1))`

main advantage being that you can pass the length and the pad character as a cell reference, and easily update

Comment: @zx8754: True... then let's combine the best of both: `=LEFT(A1 & REPT("*",5),5)`

Comment: Nice. Will keep this one in my "arsenal" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had to right pad the numbers in a cell with 0 to make it maximum 9 characters. All had uneven numbers in the cell. I used the below formula to achieve the result. For me the least characters present in the cell was 3. 
=LEFT(G41 & REPT("0",6),9)

Comment: This might be on the right track, but doesn't really answer the question. The OP shows strings padded with spaces to a length of 5, but you have padded with `0` to a length of 9.