# In Excel set number of characters in a cell and export to csv then txt with delimiters

Tags: excel

Trying to set a number of characters in a cell to 40. Converting to a CSV then to Text format that will have the 40 characters with "," delimiters in it. I.E.:

`10,HELLO                                   ,      10`

HELLO being the 40 Characters total 5 with the "HELLO" then 35 'spaces' after.

Can this be done?  I have tried Data Validation equal to 40 and does not work.

Comment: Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363823/padding-a-word-with-spaces-to-fill-a-cell

Comment: Yes! Yes, it does!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula to create a new column for your text field. This will pad the value with spaces up to 40, as well as trim to 40 if the value exceeds it.

```
    =LEFT(B2 & REPT(" ",40),40)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  Happen to know how to put leading spaces BEFORE any characters?

Comment: Well, if you want to add perhaps 5 spaces, then you could do this: ="     "&A2     where you space the number of spaces between quotes.

Comment: If you want to do everything at once (value is prefixed with 5 spaces and suffixed with enough spaces to make 40 wide), then it may look like this: =LEFT("     "&A2 & REPT(" ", 40), 40)